# Not able to change background to colour white only in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View  style={styles.container}>
      <Text>hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});*
```

All other colours working except white, was working before, restarted app and mobile expo

Comment: Make sure you clear cache and restart the expo server and run the app again.

Comment: Tried, still doesnt work for some reason

Comment: show me video  issue